# Navigating away from page referenced using iframe

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

What I have at the moment is a page which I am using as a sirt of site master for my html pages. The way I am doing this is by referencing the master page using this line of code:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="width:100%;" frameBorder="0" src="WebForm1.aspx"></iframe>
```

Now that works fine, I can create a new page and reference that, and then the content from that page will appear on any page referencing it.

But I have a problem, what I want Is if you click the navigation button that is in header of a page that is referencing this site master; it navigates away but only the iframe will hold the webpage, and the main content will still be the same.

For example:

In the master page I am referencing using the Iframe, I have some code that when you click on a button it navigates away, ok. But if I go into a page that is referencing the master and click the button, the new web page will only open in the iframe section at the top of the page.

Sorry for this complicated question, if anyone understands it, then any advice would be helpful!

The page that is referencing the master:

http://codepad.org/IyrDxAf9

The master page itself:

http://codepad.org/XMu67H1M

PS...I am coding this in asp.net using html

The aim of all this is to create a master page for html, but I am not having much luck with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the following in your webform1.aspx page:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

This will target all the links on that page to the 'parent' window.  You can also do this with individual links.

Seeing as you are using .aspx pages here, is there a reason why you are not using the built in master page functionality?

Comment: Yes!! Thankyou very much, I have been stumped on this for quite a while +1 to you sir!